# Does $\sum_{k \ \text{odd}, \ k>0}^{N} \frac{\sin(kx)}{k}$ converge to $f(x)$ uniformly?

Tags: fourier-series

I calculated the Fourier coefficients of the square wave.

$$
  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1,  & x\in [-\pi, 0) \\
1, & x\in [0, \pi]
\end{cases}
$$

Then I came to the conclusion that the $N^{th}$ partial Fourier sum is given by

$$
S_{N,f}(x) = \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{k \ \text{odd}, \ k > 0 }^{N} \frac{\sin(kx)}{k}
$$

Now does $S_{N,f}(x)$ converge to $f(x)$ uniformly?

What are some usefull theorems I can use here? Or must I prove it by def. of uniformly convergence? I found a theorem called Weierstrass M test. But I dont think it is usefull here, since the only bound for $|\frac{\sin(kx)}{k}|$ that I can come up with is $\frac{1}{k}$ which is not helpful.

Comment: $S_{N, f}$ is a continuous function. Now look at $S_{N, f}(0)$. If the sum converges uniformly, then for some $N$ we must have $S_{N, f}(0)-1<\epsilon$. By continuity, $S_{N, f}(x) > 1- 2\epsilon$ for all $-\delta<x<\delta$ for some $\delta >0$. Thus we have a problem for negative values, as $S_{N, f}(-\delta)-(-1)>2-2\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly, they converge to a continuous function (see [the uniform convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_continuity)). Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_{n,f}$ is not continuous, the convergence cannot be uniform even if you redefine your function to be $0$ at $x=0$.